# Identifying/inferring department name from large dataset with human entries, includes many languages

Tags: python, r, string, bigdata, multilingual

I have a large dataset, about 114 billion entries. These entries are human written and quite messy, and can be in any human language. The field "should" include information about academic departments.

I have been successful in isolating the more important text, some examples look like:

"GambhirComputer Engineering DepartmentAssociate Professor20060117JC Bose University of Science and TechnologyFaridabadHaryanaIN231589RINGGOLD"

"AbboodPharmacologyDr.University of Al-AmeedKarbalaaIQ"

"UniversityDept of Cultural StudiesProfessorLingnan UniversityTuen MunNew TerritoriesHKRINGGOLD"

"Cesar Oliveira VasconcelosInstituto de CiÃªncias Sociais e ComunicaÃ§Ã£o Professor titularUniversidade PaulistaSao PauloSPBRRINGGOLDCesar Oliveira VasconcelosPrograma de PÃ³s-GraduaÃ§Ã£o Mestrado e DoutoradoProfessor PermanenteUniversidade CatÃ³lica de BrasÃ­liaTaguatingaDFBRRINGGOLDCesar Oliveira VasconcelosDiretoria de Desenvolvimento SustentÃ¡velAnalista SÃªniorBanco do BrasilBrasiliaDistrito FederalBRRINGGOLD","

My goal is to mine/infer/isolate/identify the academic department from these entries. I have some powerful hardware, but, given the number of entries I have, there will be some limitation on scalability (Cant use the chatGPT api for this).

I am not asking for exact syntax per say (I will be doing this in R or python if you find providing syntax helpful in your response), but just higher level recommendations on how people would approach this.

I have tried some regex approaches, but the sheer number of possibilities has made this unmanageable to implement accurately.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, not general data analysis advice. Questions seeking recommendations for packages are specifically off topic. If you want analysis advice, try a site like [stats.se] or [datascience.se] instead.